# Windows Azure Web Service, Fails to Connect to SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, azure

I'm working on this for some time and I have no idea anymore what to do.. so here is the problem.

I've got a Azure Webservice, which works perfectly localy. It should connect to a Azure SQL Database (I use the same ConnectionString for debug AND azure.. so it SHOULD be right)

Using IntelliTrace, I find these Errors:

```
Requested registry access is not allowed.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral....
System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException    A network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct... (This about 50 times)
System.Threading.WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException              No handle of the given name exists.
System.Security.SecurityException          Requested registry access is not allowed
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironmentException        error 
System.Threading.WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException            No handle of the given name exists.
```

(Exception stack, top newest, bott oldest)

In my web.config I setup EF and ConnectionString like this:

```
<configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="EntityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework" requirePermission="false"/>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=SERVER.database.windows.net;Database=LeagueMetaDatabase;User ID=USER@ksew7pk8ad;Password=PW;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I also deactivated "Specific Version" for the EF assembly and activated "Copy Local".
I checked in the bin folder of the service on the server, the dll is there.

The service uses a lot of async, but as already said it works localy.. I also installed .NET 4.5.1 on the server just to be sure that is not the problem

// Edit
First of all, thanks for all the help so far!

I tried narrowing the problem down.. reconstructing the hole project and trying to find what does not work. It seems that async Tasks can NOT read the ConnectionString in the Web.config on the Azure Server Cloud. In the emulator, it works. I hardcoded the ConnectionString into the Context and it is working this way.

Anyone can tell me what creates this behaviour and how I can put it back into the Web.config?

Comment: how are you deploying to Azure? if you're using "publish" method from within VS then you might check if you have proper connection strings set up - I remember that Visual Studio replaced connection strings from development to production, you might check that. Also I don't recommend using anything that's not Stable on Azure - I've had many problems with that too (and I see you're using EF 6).

Comment: What's in the <runtime> tag in web.config? Which EF does it reference?

Comment: I have no runtime tag in my web.config of the service

Comment: I'm using publish from VS 2013 RC, I checked the web.config on the server and it does not change the connection string

Comment: <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    </system.web>

Comment: I tried it with the following <runtime> and it didn't help


     `<runtime>
       <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publ icKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
         </dependentAssembly>
       </assemblyBinding>
     </runtime>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks for all the help so far!

I tried narrowing the problem down.. reconstructing the hole project and trying to find what does not work. 
It seems that async Tasks can NOT read the ConnectionString in the Web.config on the Azure Server Cloud. In the emulator, it works. I hardcoded the ConnectionString into the Context and it is working this way.

Anyone can tell me what creates this behaviour and how I can put it back into the Web.config?

Answer (score 2):

How is your solution deployed to Azure? Are you using a Cloud Service or Web Site? If you're running an Azure Web Site the problem might be related to your connection string name being the same in both the web.config and also your Azure Web Site. If this is the case you might want to try renaming the connection string defined in the Azure Management Portal for you web site. This can be done through the **Configure** management page.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are the DB & Cloud Service in same data center?  If not, link your resources via the Azure control panel and/or make sure that you have enabled "allow azure services to connect" in the DB configure section.

Also, make sure your SERVER connection specifies "tcp" - The Windows Azure SQL Database service is only available with TCP port 1433. To access a SQL Database database from your computer, ensure that your firewall allows outgoing TCP communication on TCP port 1433 (from [Guidelines for Connecting to Windows Azure SQL Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336282.aspx)).  If you grab the ADO connection string from the DB dashboard page, you should see:

```
Server=tcp:{your_servername}.database.windows.net,1433;Database={your_database_name};User ID={your_userid};Password={your_password_here};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;
```

Comment: Yes they are in the same Center! Linking em actualy only links em to the dashboard.. it doesn't change anything else!

Comment: @AlexejHaak I thought "it doesn't change anything else!" as well - but I, like you, was wrong.  If you go to the configure tab on your web service you will see the connection information for your database and server (I only have a mobile service set up at the moment - but I had exactly the problem you are describing).  I found that these values did need to be set correctly (by linking resource) to get my database connections to function correctly.  It came as a surprise to me too.  These values appear to be transformed into your config file automagically...